# How to get everything after first '?' from any url?

Tags: php, url

I am working on a project and need to store everything after the first `?` in url into a new php variable.

I know that it may be done by `strpos` function but I am little confused and don't know how to do it.

For eg this is my question.

If the url is `www.domain.com/abcd?uj=34&kku=oo9`
I need to store `uj=34&kku=oo9` into a new php variable.

```
 $id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '?' )+1 );
```

This function does the similar job not exactly it finds the last `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: `strrpos` returns the last occurence, `strpos` returns the first occurence

You can also use `parse_url` on this case:

```
$url = 'www.domain.com/abcd?uj=34&kku=oo9';
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
echo $query_string; // uj=34&kku=oo9
```

Comment: @anamika could you clarify your question. its stated in your question: `store everything after the first ?`, now what is it that you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = explode("?","www.domain.com/abcd?uj=34&kku=oo9");
echo $str[count($str)-1];
```

Comment: Better to use parse_url, see other answer

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over the GET array, like so:

```
end = "";
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    end .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
}
```

That'll leave you with an extra ampersand at the end, so be sure to trim that off after the foreach loop.

I must add a friendly reminder never to trust input that users submit or can edit. Take care not to use the GET values in a way that could let a hacker do damage or gain access with a crafted URL.